# How can I archive a social media site that is not owned by me?

Tags: facebook, twitter, instagram, archive, social-media

I am an archivist looking to archiving social media pages (Twitter, Facebook, Instagram). I run into a lot of companies (such as[Archive Social](https://archivesocial.com/), [PageFreezer](https://www.pagefreezer.com/social-media-archiving/), etc.) that will archive social media, but using the owner accounts to grab the data. Other web archiving tools I have tried (such as [Archive It](https://archive-it.org/)) have issues grabbing all the data due to the nature of social media pages (scrolling, comments, etc.).

Would creating an RSS feed be my best bet? Or am I missing other tools that could do this job? I am in the process of learning more about digital preservation and archiving so any help would be appreciated.